# where to find missing tlc file generated by simulink?

Tags: matlab, arduino, real-time, simulink

please help with this problem

while i am trying to deploy a model into Arduino mega from my 2013a 32bit matlab i had this error.
( The corresponding 'Model name.tlc' file for the MATLAB S-function 'Model name' in block 'block name' must be located in the current working directory, ...)

i have looked in many websites and forums for solution but i couldn't find, maybe because i am not familiar with matlab much. but i guess the problem is with S-function. i noticed that it is easy to get tlc file if i use s-function builder. but the current model i am trying to deploy is {M-S-Function: User-definable block written using the MATLAB S-Function API...}

what shall i do?

Comment: If you've written a custom m-code S-Function, and you want to use it with code generation, then you need to write a custom .tlc file too. Simulink will not generate it for you, and it is missing because you haven't written it.  There is no workaround for this.

Comment: Thanks @PhilGoddard. that make sense. is that same to the other files like wrapper.cpp file and mexw32 file and all the other generated files i have to write them or only tlc file?

Comment: The .mexw32 file is a compiled dll for a c-code S-Function.  The wrapper.cpp file is something generated by the S-Function Builder.  Both are related to c-code S-Functions and have nothing to do with m-code S-Functions.

Answer (score 0):

after i used newer version of matlab and newer version of the support package i was able to generate automatically all the files including tlc file.

Comment: well, later on I found this was only for the first time i used that version. but after i edited it and tried to build again the problem occur again.